# Memory leak on ruby process after upgrading to OSX Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-lion

I upgraded to Lion few weeks ago, and it completely screwed by Ruby on Rails environment. I have installing RVM, different ruby versions and can't seem to find a solution for it... I think it was one of the worst decisions I could do upgrading to Lion. It only brought problems to me.

Anyway, I have realised that rendering a page of my application (which works perfectly well on deployed server and locally too in other machines) increases the ruby process memory in 20-30mb which is kind of crazy. So you can imagine that after a while, my ruby process reaches 2gb of memory in use and my computer is not usable anymore.

I have seen many people with problems upgrading to Lion but I have not been able to find a solution for my case.

Any had the same problem? Any ideas how could I try to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Having the same problem. Pol, did you find a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem and am looking for a solution.

Comment: Could you post the code associated with the page that causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [memprof](https://github.com/ice799/memprof) gem (**No longer maintained** and doesn't work for Ruby above version 1.8.7) and <strike>[memprof.com](http://memprof.com/)</strike> (Broken Link) to get to the bottom of the issue.

Also you could experiment with using Passenger, Unicorn or Thin instead of the default Webrick to see if that gives you different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you might fix the memory leak, but can propose one way to contain it and further troubleshoot it.

If you are willing to learn Docker, you can contain your development environment inside a Docker container, all while accessing the code on your local machine, just like a shared folder in Vagrant.

When you run the Docker container that runs, you can specify a limit on the amount of memory that container can use. Your `rails server` process might crash and stop the container, but at least you won't have to restart your machine.

Maybe that will give you more leeway for troubleshooting the problem in greater depth.

[Docker Run Reference](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/), see the section "Runtime constraints on CPU and memory".